# Centering Input And Select Fields in Fieldset

Tags: html, css

I am making an app where I am using a fieldset to collect information. I am currently trying to center the input and select fields in the fieldset and I am having trouble doing so. Here is the HTML:

```
          <fieldset>
            <legend align = "center">Enter Income Here</legend>
            <p>
              <label>Hourly Rate: </label>
              <input type="number" min="0" placeholder="Hourly Rate" id="Rate">
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>Hours Per Week: </label>
              <input type="number" min="0" max="40" placeholder="Hours / Week" id="HoursPer">
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>Overtime Hours / Week: </label>
              <input type="number" min="0" placeholder="Overtime Hours / Week" id="OvertimePer">
            </p>
            <hr style="visibility: visible;">
            <p>
                <label>Federal Taxes: </label>
                <input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="Federal Tax %" id="Federal">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>State Taxes: </label>
                <input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="State Tax %" id="State">
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>Fica Taxes: </label>
              <input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="Other Tax %" id="Other">
            </p>
            <hr style="visibility: visible;">
            <p>
                <label>Frequency: </label>
                <select name="frequency" id="frequency">
                  <option value="" selected="selected">Select Frequency</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>Status: </label>
              <select name="status" id="status">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Frequency First</option>
              </select>
            </p>
          </fieldset>
```

And the CSS for the fieldset:

```
  fieldset {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 500px;
    max-width: 500px;
    border: 2px groove;
    margin-bottom: 350px;
  }

  fieldset legend {
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  fieldset p {
    display: table-row;
  }
  
  fieldset input, fieldset select, fieldset label {
    display: table-cell;
  }

  fieldset input, fieldset select {
    min-width: 250px;
  }
  
  fieldset label {
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: small;
  }
```

Right now it is aligning on the left hand side of the fieldset. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:flex;` with `flex-direction: column;` and `align-items: center;` on the parent element.

Note on alignment when using display flex:

- If your ***flex-direction*** is set to default (*row*) then use
  ***justify-content*** to align items along the ***x axis***.
- If your ***flex-direction*** is set as (*column*) then use ***align-items*** to align items along the x axis.
- Reverse this for aligning items along on the ***y axis***

If you want the input labels to be centered over the inputs use the same `display:flex;` with `flex-direction: column;` and `align-items: center;` on the `p` tags selectors.

```css
fieldset {
  display: flex; /* added */
  flex-direction: column; /* added */
  align-items: center; /* added */
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 2px groove;
  margin-bottom: 350px;
}

hr { 
  width: 100%; /* added */
}

fieldset legend {
  font-size: x-large;
  font-weight: bold;
}

fieldset p {  
  display: flex; /* added */
  /* added change this to column to place the labels on top of the inputs*/
  align-items: center; /* added */
}

fieldset input,
fieldset select,
fieldset label {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

fieldset input,
fieldset select {
  min-width: 250px;
}

fieldset label {
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: small;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend align="center">Enter Income Here</legend>
  <p>
    <label>Hourly Rate: </label>
    <input type="number" min="0" placeholder="Hourly Rate" id="Rate">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Hours Per Week: </label>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="40" placeholder="Hours / Week" id="HoursPer">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Overtime Hours / Week: </label>
    <input type="number" min="0" placeholder="Overtime Hours / Week" id="OvertimePer">
  </p>
  <hr style="visibility: visible;">
  <p>
    <label>Federal Taxes: </label>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="Federal Tax %" id="Federal">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>State Taxes: </label>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="State Tax %" id="State">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Fica Taxes: </label>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="Other Tax %" id="Other">
  </p>
  <hr style="visibility: visible;">
  <p>
    <label>Frequency: </label>
    <select name="frequency" id="frequency">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select Frequency</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Status: </label>
    <select name="status" id="status">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select Frequency First</option>
    </select>
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: How would I make those label show up on the side instead of on top?

Comment: Just change the p tags flex-direction to row or simply remove it all together.

Comment: Happy to help out.